# How to resolve sinonJS stub?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vuex, sinon

So I'm trying to stub a request with SinonJS.
Before each test it should mock the request with resolved fake info, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Tried resolving with `Promise.resolve`, but it also doesn't work as I expected.

Here's the test code:

```
describe("Store | Users actions", () => {
  let commit = null;
  let page = 1;
  let itemsPerPage = 2;

  const users_response = {
    status: 200,
    data: [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Leanne Graham",
      "username": "Bret",
      "email": "Sincere@april.biz"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Ervin Howell",
      "username": "Antonette",
      "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv"
    }]
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    commit = sinon.spy();
    sinon
      .stub(api.users, "list").resolves();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    api.users.list.restore();
  });

  it("should list users", () => {
    users.actions.list({ commit }, { page, itemsPerPage });
    expect(commit).to.have.been.calledWith("UNSET_ERROR");
    expect(commit).to.have.been.calledWith("GET_PAGINATED", users_response);
  });
});
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
  1) Store | Users actions
       should list users:
     AssertionError: expected spy to have been called with arguments GET_PAGINATED, {
  data: [{ email: "Sincere@april.biz", id: 1, name: "Leanne Graham", username: "Bret" }, { email: "Shanna@melissa.tv", id: 2, name: "Ervin Howell", username: "Antonette" }],
  status: 200
}
"UNSET_ERROR" "GET_PAGINATED"
{
  data: [{ email: "Sincere@april.biz", id: 1, name: "Leanne Graham", username: "Bret" }, { email: "Shanna@melissa.tv", id: 2, name: "Ervin Howell", username: "Antonette" }],
  status: 200
}
      at Context.<anonymous> (dist/js/webpack:/tests/unit/store/users.spec.js:184:1)
```

```
list({ commit }, { page, itemsPerPage, sort, search }) {
      commit("UNSET_ERROR");

      return api.users
        .list(page, itemsPerPage, sort, search)
        .then((users) => commit("GET_PAGINATED", users.data))
        .catch((error) => commit("SET_ERROR", error));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: added list function

Comment: Please provide the code you want to test.

Comment: You error message means: your second expect is failing, because: (maybe) your spy (commit) was not get called with arguments "GET_PAGINATED" (as 1st arg) and users_response (as 2nd arg). Your spy was get called only once with 1 arg "UNSET_ERROR". Nothing wrong with it, your unit test works as expected, because you do not provide the code under test and the context.

Comment: I've added the function that I'm trying to test

Comment: maybe worth putting in an assertion to check that `commit('SET_ERROR')` was NOT called

Comment: I've added the assertion to check that, it's not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your second commit function call is inside Promise then method.

You need to await for users.actions.list().

For example:

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
    commit = sinon.spy();
    // Note: add users_response here.
    sinon.stub(api.users, "list").resolves(users_response);
  });

  // Use async here.
  it("should list users", async () => {
    // Use await here.
    await users.actions.list({ commit }, { page, itemsPerPage });
    expect(commit).to.have.been.calledWith("UNSET_ERROR");
    // Note: expect with property data, because called with: users.data.
    expect(commit).to.have.been.calledWith("GET_PAGINATED", users_response.data);
  });
```